# Preview not displaying any letters while typing in search box

Tags: html, css, ibm-mobilefirst

In jsfiddle.net it's working but not when previewing the app from the worklight console: http://jsfiddle.net/sphakrrokr/k4L6ej9z/6/

before, when the simple html was written it was working good but the position was not side by side search box and go buttton

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" data-mini="true" placeholder="Search for Restaurants" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">
<input type="submit" value="Go" data-inline="true" id ="submit" onclick="getRestaurants()">
```

after that some changes for positioning side by side, but afterwards text is not displayed when typing...

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #the-page {float:center;width:100%}
    #submit_con {width:20%; float:left;}
    #search_con {width:80%; float:left;}
    #search {width:100%;}
    #submit {width:100%;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="header" id="the-page" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>YUMMY</h3>

            <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Favs" id="favs" data-icon="star">Favs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#myPanel" id="more" data-icon="bars">More</a></li><!-- PANEL LINK -->
            </ul>
        </div>

            <label for="search" id="label" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-family: Comic Sans MS"></label>

<div id ="search_con">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" data-mini="true" placeholder="Search for Restaurants" data-theme="a">
    </div>
    <div id="submit_con">
<input type="submit" value="Go" data-inline="true" id ="submit" onclick="getRestaurants()">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've provided incomplete HTML...
Anyway, you are only missing a DIV, but this is nothing something that will make the textfield inoperable. That said, it's working fine regardless.

I've copied your HTML into a new project+application (created with the jQuery Mobile wizard in MFP Studio) followed by Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server. When previewing the common web resources from MFP Console and trying to type in the text field - it's working:

[image]

common\index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>test</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <div data-role="header" id="the-page" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>YUMMY</h3>

                <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Favs" id="favs" data-icon="star">Favs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#myPanel" id="more" data-icon="bars">More</a></li><!-- PANEL LINK -->
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <label for="search" id="label" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-family: Comic Sans MS"></label>

                <div id ="search_con">
                    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" data-mini="true" placeholder="Search for Restaurants" data-theme="a">
                </div>
                <div id="submit_con">
                    <input type="submit" value="Go" data-inline="true" id ="submit" onclick="getRestaurants()">
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

common\css\main.css

```
#the-page {float:center;width:100%}
#submit_con {width:20%; float:left;}
#search_con {width:80%; float:left;}
#search {width:100%;}
#submit {width:100%;}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with worklight 5 ?and mobile first 7 update version solved this issue?

Comment: No, because nothing here is related to Worklight. 5 or 7. It's pure HTML.